# calculate number of viewer and ticket price

Tags: java

This is for my assignment, it asks the user to enter a day of the week and it will display the cost. I would like to get more information from the user by asking for the number of the viewer in order to calculate the total amount of pricing for the ticket. This is my code.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Prompt user to enter the day of the week
    System.out.println("Please enter the day of the week:");
    day = keyboard.nextLine();

    switch (day){
    // User can input the days in different ways and the cost will be printed
    case "Monday":
    case "monday":
    case "MONDAY":
                  System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM 5.");
                  break;

    case "Tuesday":
    case "tuesday":
    case "TUESDAY":
                   System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM 5.");
                   break;

    case "Wednesday":
    case "wednesday":
    case "WEDNESDAY":
                    System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM 5.");
                    break;

    case "Thursday":
    case "thursday":
    case "THURSDAY":
                    System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM 10.");
                    break;

    case "Friday":
    case "friday":
    case "FRIDAY":
                    System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM 20.");
                    break;

    case "Saturday":
    case "saturday":
    case "SATURDAY":
                    System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM 30.");
                    break;

    case "Sunday":
    case "sunday":
    case "SUNDAY":
                    System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM 20.");
                    break;

    default:
            System.out.println("Please make sure you made the correct input.");
            keyboard.close();


    }   

}
```

}

Comment: And what problem are you facing?

Comment: I am confused on what the question is. Also, just use toLowerCase() so you are not replicating the days.

Comment: its not a problem. i would like to add on additional information by calculating the total price

Comment: You mean you want to add something like `numberOfPeople =  keyboard.nextLine();`?

Comment: We can give you hints to solve your assignment. You need not hardcode the cost inside the string that you print. An array of size 7 can hold the cost. When you accept number of viewers from user, you multiply that by cost[day_Index] then print the result. You may also use a Map to hold the cost with day string as the key and cost Integer as value.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand this should be the solution to your problem

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
// Prompt user to enter the day of the week
System.out.println("Please enter the day of the week:");
//Make the input with lowercase/uppercase so that you don't need to check with many cases
String day = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
//Input the number of viewers
System.out.println("Please enter how many viewer are there:");
int viewers = keyboard.nextInt();
//Define a price
int price=0;
switch (day) {
    // User can input the days in different ways and the cost will be printed
    case "monday":
        price=5;
        System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM"+price+".");
        price = price*viewers;
        System.out.println("The cost of all the movie tickets is RM"+price+".");
        break;


    case "tuesday":
        price=5;
        System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM"+price+".");
        price = price*viewers;
        System.out.println("The cost of all the movie tickets is RM"+price+".");
        break;


    case "wednesday":
        price=5;
        System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM"+price+".");
        price = price*viewers;
        System.out.println("The cost of all the movie tickets is RM"+price+".");
        break;

    case "thursday":
        price=10;
        System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM"+price+".");
        price = price*viewers;
        System.out.println("The cost of all the movie tickets is RM"+price+".");
        break;

    case "FRIDAY":
        price=20;
        System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM"+price+".");
        price = price*viewers;
        System.out.println("The cost of all the movie tickets is RM"+price+".");
        break;


    case "saturday":
        price=30;
        System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM"+price+".");
        price = price*viewers;
        System.out.println("The cost of all the movie tickets is RM"+price+".");
        break;


    case "sunday":
        price=20;
        System.out.println("The cost of the movie ticket is RM"+price+".");
        price = price*viewers;
        System.out.println("The cost of all the movie tickets is RM"+price+".");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Please make sure you made the correct input.");
        keyboard.close();

}
```

Please tell me if this is what you wanted

Comment: My bad Friday should be friday